# Запятые при повторе союза «или»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, или

> Бранные слова или удаляй или заменяй на многоточие.

> Бранные слова или удаляй, или заменяй на многоточия, или подыщи бранному слову цензурную замену.

Подскажите, правильно ли поставлены запятые? Пытался разобраться самостоятельно, но правила их расстановки в предложениях с «или» выглядят для меня очень запутанными.

Comment: _Бранные слова или удаляй, или заменяй на многоточия, **либо** подыщи бранному слову цензурную замену._ Третье "или" здесь стилистически неудачно, поскольку присоединяет относительно неоднородную конструкцию к паре однородных.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Бранные слова* [ты] *или удаляй, или заменяй на многоточие.* [+ запятая перед вторым "или"]
*Бранные слова* [ты] *или удаляй, или заменяй на многоточия, или подыщи бранному слову цензурную замену.*

Простой сочинительный союз «или» по своему смыслу — разделительный.
Он используется для того, чтобы противопоставлять друг другу члены одного предложения (или предложения целиком), а также уточнять значение одного из членов предложения.

Оба предложения являются простыми, осложнены однородными членами (сказуемыми).
Перед «или» запятая ставится, если союзы повторяются — перед каждым, кроме первого.

*Притом всякий вечно позабывал в кухне **или** шапку, **или** кнут для чужих собак, **или** что-нибудь подобное* (Н. В. Гоголь); *Колоть беспрестанно мне глаза цыганской жизнью **или** глупо, **или** безжалостно* (А. Н. Островский).

[Однородные члены предложения, соединенные повторяющимися союзами](http://orthographia.ru/punctum.php?paragraph=pg26.php)

Во втором предложении я бы предложила использовать глаголы одного вида: *удаляй, заменяй, подыскивай* (или *удали, замени, подыщи*).

Comment: Спасибо большое.